# Customize data lables into pie chart using jqPlot.

Tags: java, android, jquery, jqplot, pie-chart

How can I design such pie chart like below image.

[image]

---

*I am reading about jqPlot (in to Android applications) so I am trying to implement a graph like same as above. I learned about Pie Chart and read [example given on jqPlot Doc Example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php).*

The main problem is I have no idea how to customize data lables like added image. Please provide some idea/ example/ or article which can be helpful. If this is possible by another library please guide me that API.

Comment: I tagged the question in to Android also. Because I am trying jqPlot into Android.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to add images to the labels, but you can take a look at the jqPlot documentation for DonutRenderer, which seems to be the closest to what you need: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-donutRenderer-js.html